# What are linux headers and why do we need them

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I need to install CUDA key-rings, so before installing that i need to install Linux header files, so what is Linux header files and what is the purpose of the header files.

Answer (score 6):

Linux headers are declarations of a programming interface needed to interface with Linux kernel.

In short, if you have a program that talks with the kernel, to build that program, you need those files.

The purpose is to provide the header files in one place, otherwise each program would need to have a copy of the header files, and that would be a mess when something in the header files gets changed.

Comment: why do we need a copy of each program.

Comment: hello, edited. Copy of the interface, not the program.

Answer (score -4):

Basically the Linux equivalent of .net libraries.

Comment: ... which inevitably leads to the question: "What is a .net library?" Please read [answer] and [edit] this post to make it clear to people wanting to use Linux headers but who aren't necessarily .net gurus.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).